# FullCalendar - Vertical timeline, horizontal days

Tags: fullcalendar

I would like to know, if there is any way to create a calendar with FullCalendar in such format:

[image]

I formed resusers in the form of dates. But I see events only in one day. It is possible to correct the events. But maybe there is a way to display all the days in this format.

Thank you in advance!

Temporarily, I solved the problem this way:

```
 <div class="panel-body">
      <div id="calendar"></div>
 </div>

@section Styles {
    <link href="~/lib/fullcalendar/dist/fullcalendar.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="~/lib/fullcalendar-scheduler/dist/scheduler.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
}
@section Scripts {
    <script src="~/lib/moment/moment.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/fullcalendar/dist/fullcalendar.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/fullcalendar/dist/locale/ru.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/fullcalendar-scheduler/dist/scheduler.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function () {
                $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
                    defaultView: 'timelineDay',
                    slotDuration: '00:30',
                    slotWidth: 5,
                    height: 'auto',
                    eventOverlap: false,
                    nowIndicator: true,
                    businessHours: true,
                    defaultDate: "@DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM")-01",
                    titleFormat: 'MMMM YYYY',
                    header: {
                        left: 'myPrevButton,myNextButton',
                        center: 'title',
                        right: ''
                    },
                    customButtons: {
                        myNextButton: {
                            //text: 'Next',
                            icon: 'right-single-arrow',
                            click: function () {
                                $('#calendar').fullCalendar('incrementDate', {
                                    months: 1,                                    
                                });
                                $('#calendar').fullCalendar('refetchResources');                                
                            }
                        },
                        myPrevButton: {
                            //text: 'Prev',
                            icon: 'left-single-arrow',
                            click: function () {
                                $('#calendar').fullCalendar('incrementDate', {
                                    months: -1,
                                });
                                $('#calendar').fullCalendar('refetchResources');                                
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    events: "/api/Sheduling/eventpersonal/@Model.Id",
                    refetchResourcesOnNavigate: true,
                    resources: '/api/Sheduling/1'
                });
        });
    </script>
}
```

This solution works for me. But it requires superfluous operations.
This solution works for me. But it requires superfluous operations. I receive a schedule for one employee in the form of:

Resources:

```
[{"id":1,"title":"1/8"},{"id":2,"title":"2/8"},{"id":3,"title":"3/8"},{"id":4,"title":"4/8"},{"id":5,"title":"5/8"},{"id":6,"title":"6/8"}, ....
```

Events (where all start in the end date is the 1st day of the month, and the resourceId is the date of the month):

```
[{"color":"#006633","id":1,"resourceId":1,"start":"2018-08-01T10:05:00","end":"2018-08-01T10:09:50"},{"color":"#006633","id":1,"resourceId":1,"start":"2018-08-01T10:35:00","end":"2018-08-01T10:39:50"},{"color":"#006633","id":1,"resourceId":1,"start":"2018-08-01T11:05:00","end":"2018-08-01T11:09:50"},{"color":"#006633","id":1,"resourceId":1,"start":"2018-08-01T11:35:00","end":"2018-08-01T11:39:50"},{"color":"#006633","id":1,"resourceId":1,"start":"2018-08-01T12:05:00","end":"2018-08-01T12:09:50"},{"color":"#006633","id":1,"resourceId":1,"start":"2018-08-01T12:35:00","end":"2018-08-01T12:39:50"},{"color":"#006633","id":1,"resourceId":1,"start":"2018-08-01T13:05:00","end":"2018-08-01T13:09:50"},{"color":"#006633","id":1,"resourceId":1,"start":"2018-08-01T13:35:00","end":"2018-08-01T13:39:50"},{"color":"#006633","id":1,"resourceId":1,"start":"2018-08-01T14:05:00","end":"2018-08-01T14:09:50"},{"color":"#006633","id":1,"resourceId":1,"start":"2018-08-01T14:35:00","end":"2018-08-01T14:39:50"}, ....
```

Comment: "I formed resusers in the form of dates" I have no idea what this sentence means. Please try to express yourself clearly and precisely in relation to fullCalendar and/or JavaScript features. Also show some code if it helps. It looks like you're using the Scheduler plugin and trying to pretend that resources are days? I doubt this will ever work as you expect. To truly get the view you want, you'd have to write one of these: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/custom-view-with-js - not a simple or quick task. Consider whether there's another way to represent your data which will be adequate instead.

Comment: I created Resources in the form of the date of the month